# How to make mixins work in react es6?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am learning meteor and reactjs. I have encountered to mixins functionality. I am using es6 where mixin is removed. How can i now enjoy the functionality of mixins in my react es6 code?

**Here is a code**

**mixins used**

```
Signupform = React.createClass({
    mixins: [ReactMeteorData],
    getMeteorData(){
        let data = {};
        data.currentUser = Meteor.user();
        return data;
    },
    getInitialState(){
        return {
            message: '',
            messageClass: 'hidden'
        }
    },
    render(){

    }
});
```

**can't use mixins so how can i make this code work**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class SignupForm extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            message:'',
            messageClass:''
        }
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    getMeteorData(){
            let data = {};
            data.currentUser = Meteor.user();
            console.log('data',data);
            return data;
        }

    render(){
        return(
            )
    }
}
```

Same mixins is used in several other components. I am following tutorial of building social network with meteor and reactjs.

Comment: You should also read this article https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750#.jpbjhorfv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const ReactMeteorDataWrap = (BaseComponent)=>{
    return class ExportClass extends Component { 
        getMeteor(){
            //todo::some code to get Metor
        }
        render(){
            return <BaseComponent getMeteor={()=>this.getMeteor()} 
                 {...this.props}></BaseComponent>
        }
    }
}

export default ReactMeteorDataWrap
```

u can use it like

```
 class SignupForm extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            message:'',
            messageClass:''
        }
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    getMeteorData(){
            let data = {};
            data.currentUser = this.props.getMeteor().user();
            console.log('data',data);
            return data;
        }

    render(){
        return(
            )
    }
}
export default ReactMeteorDataWrap(SignupForm)
```

Comment: If i want to call this SignupForm component what should i do now? Can i still call it using import SignupForm from '../signup/SignupForm.jsx'; because now export default ReactMeteorDataWrap is used?

Comment: there is no difference in using